# Is using JSON as HTTP GET input Paramter a valid RESTful Service?

Tags: rest, http, get

I have the following Backend API:

#### Endpoint

**HTTP GET**

```
https://localhost:8443/getSomeParameterInfo
```

#### Query Parameter

`?inputAsJson`

**example**

```
{
  'url': 'http://semanticstuff.org/blah#Parameter,
  'parameters_1': 'value1',
  'someArray': [
     'http://semanticstuff.org/blah#something1,
     'http://semanticstuff.org/blah#something2
  ],
  'someOtherArray': [
     'http://....'
  ]
}
```

the Final HTTP GET Call is

> https://localhost:8443/getSomeParameterInfo?inputAsJson={aboveMentioned JSON}

Due to everchanging requirements for the Backend, the above mentioned JSON Structure keep increasing by addition of new key:value pairs. (This JSON Structure is also a query for a database)

#### Hinderances

Due to uses of weblinks as values it becomes necessary to use `encodeURIComponent` function for a successful REST Call. This means, the quotes, forward slashses etc. need to be encoded to get a Reply. This becomes quite tedious when one requires to do tests on standalone basis (using Postman or other REST Clients)

I have not seen a JSON structure passed to an API as mentioned above and hence I wish to confirm about the *best practices* and/or proper way to use large number of parameters when making such a RESTful call

Answer (score 1):

I usually tend to think that getting something via a `POST` is a "bad" practice.

However, it sounds like body in `GET` is not something forbidden but still something not widely implemented in frameworks.

In your case, it will depends on how many attributes you have and the global length or your json.

If you keep on using `GET` method, then using an "exploded" key-value representation of your JSON should be the way to go.

Exemple:
`{ "myKey": "myValue", "childObjKey": {"childObjProp": "childValue}}`
could become
`?myKey=myValue&childObjKey.childObjProp=childValue`

But there are some limits on query parmeters' length which can be implemented in clients and/or servers. 
If your number of parameters is huge and values' length are unpredictable (text without length limit for instance), then using `POST` should be the way to go.

Comment: Here is a just an [example](https://pastebin.com/zu7CnDnc) when a user selects one Parameter from the UI. It has been URIencoded, hence a bit ugly. Once the parameters increase I guess HTTP Post would be a better option